# REST API: Error 'METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED' - PATCH

Tags: rest-api, error-messages, python, simple-salesforce

I am trying to upload new records by calling a REST API but am getting the following error.

```
simple_salesforce.exceptions.SalesforceGeneralError: Error Code 405. Response content: [{'errorCode': 'METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED', 'message': "HTTP Method 'PATCH' not allowed. Allowed are GET,HEAD,POST"}]
```

Here is my code:

```
session_id, instance = SalesforceLogin(username='name@company.com.sandbox',
                                                         password=password,
                                                         security_token=token,
                                                         domain='test')

sf = Salesforce(session_id=session_id,
                instance=instance)

account = SFType('Account', session_id, instance)


upload_data = {"Name": "Test Company"}

record_id = 'Id'
account.upsert(record_id=record_id, data=upload_data)
print('done')
```

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce Error Codes can be found here [REST API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/errorcodes.htm)

405 errors usually occur when the endpoint is not formatted correctly:

> The method specified in the Request-Line isn’t allowed for the
> resource specified in the URI.

In your case, it looks like you are trying to send a PATCH request to `/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Account/Id`, where 'Id' should be the actual `001...` 15 (case-sensitive) /18 (case-insensitive) character long Account Id.

This is easily replicated:
[image]

Comment: I'm new to Salesforce APIs. What's the best practice around upserting new records via REST API? I am a bit confused on what to use for the external id. My goal is to be able to bulk upload new / update existing records. @gale-force-wizard

Comment: @ParthPatel Salesforce provides great learning resources on Trailhead.  I'd suggest you start there:  https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/api_basics/api_basics_rest

Comment: Great will look into it. Thank you!